# Sort entries by most popular

Tags: entries, sorting, custom

I'm in charge of creating a website with a 'most popular' section.

I was wondering if there was any native way/plugin that lets me sort craft entries based on most popular?

I know Expression Engine has view tracking, I'm not sure if Craft does anything similar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on how you want to determine "most popular"...

If you want to calculate based on **page views**, then check out Ben Croker's [**Entry Count plugin**](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/entry-count) (as Brad mentioned in his answer).

If you want your users to **vote** on most popular, then check out my [**Upvote plugin**](https://www.doublesecretagency.com/plugins/upvote), designed to emulate Stack Exchange or Facebook "likes".

Answer (score 2):

Nothing native, but you could probably pull it off either with this [plugin](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/entry-count) or something similar to it.